# What am I missing about passing values to an object during instantiation?

Tags: java

I'm in my first few weeks of java and I understand the relationships between these concepts, but I'm trying to pass values to a child object during instantiation and I'm missing something about how the pieces fit together. Why am I getting errors and how do I structure my code/what syntax am I missing to be able to create an instance of child and then print that object's values?

```
package child;

import static child.Gender.FEMALE;
import static child.Gender.MALE;
public class Child {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Gender Gender;

    public void eat(){}

    public void sleep(){}

    public void cry(){}

    public Child main(String name, int age, Gender gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.Gender = Gender;
        return null;
    }


    Child childOne = new Child(String "tom", int 3, Gender MALE);

    System.out.println(childOne);
    //Child childTwo = new Child();
    //Child childThree = new Child("Tammy",1,FEMALE);

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: try that : `Child childOne = new Child("tom", 3, Gender.MALE);`

Comment: Adding to what @davidxxx said, the last line should also be in a method.

Comment: ^^ e.g., you don't supply the type of the argument when you supply it. *Parameters* (the thing you declare on the method) have types, arguments you just pass in (their types come from the expression that creates them).

Comment: Also, "`private Gender gender;`" and "`this.gender=gender;`"

Comment: Syntax error on token "." @ expected after this token
Syntax error, on insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderName
Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete QualifiedName
the constructor Child(String, int, Gender) is undefined

Comment: **edit** your question, do not use comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing a constructor and the main method.

```
public class Child {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Gender gender;

    public void eat(){}

    public void sleep(){}

    public void cry(){}

    public Child (String name, int age, Gender gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {
        Child childOne = new Child("tom", 3, Gender.MALE);
        System.out.println(childOne);    
    }
}
```

Also, when calling a function, don't add the type of the argument you are passing.